# Remove all letters from a Code in SSIS in Derived column transformation editor

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have these codes in SSIS:

```
102022A
1035C
102074A
102074D
174Z
```

I would like to remove the letters (last string) of my codes to return the data like this:

```
102022
1035
102074
102074
174
```

How I can do this in SSIS? Which proper function should I use?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming we can rely on there only being one letter, which also always occurs at the end of the code, we can use `SUBSTRING` here:

```sql
SELECT code, SUBSTRING(code, 1, LEN(code) - 1) AS code_out
FROM yourTable;
```

If you actually want to modify the codes in your table, then use an update with similar logic:

```sql
UPDATE yourTable
SET code = SUBSTRING(code, 1, LEN(code) - 1)
WHERE code LIKE '%[A-Z]';
```